# How to make store.dispatch() available in an action.js file apart from getting it as props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently, I'm dispatching actions from my **redux-aware** `Login` component using `connect()` like below which is working just fine:

```
import LoginActions from '../actions';
@connect(store() => store);
...
this.props.dispatch(LoginActions.fetchingUser(formData));
```

The `fetchingUser` action creator calls an API like below:

```
import API from '../utils/api';
...
function fetchingUser(data) {
  API.getUser(data)
  return {
    type: FETCHING_USER
}
```

Inside of the `api.js` file looks like this:

```
getUser: (data) => {
  request.post('something.com', data)
    .end((err, res) => {
      err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res)
  })
}
```

**Now what I want is to be able to `dispatch` actions based on the API call responses inside of the `LoginActions.js` file or directly from the `api.js` file and for that to happen `dispatch()` needs to be available in either of these locations.**

The app folder structure is as follows(might be irrelevant):

```
├── actions
|   └── LoginActions.js
├── components
|   └── Login.jsx
├── reducer
|   └── loginReducer.js
├── utils
    └── api.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middle-ware and you will have access inside your thunk action:

```
function fetchingUser(data) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
   API.getUser(data)
   .then(response => {
        if(response.condition){
            dispatch({type: YOUR_TYPE});
        }
   })
  };
}
```

Don't forget to add the middle-ware to your store configuration:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined".

Comment: the `API.getUser` should return a promise.

Comment: figured out why the request was not returning a promise, issue got solved, thanks...

Comment: Well yeah, you didn't return anything just did `console.log` :)